# How can I append union of timestamp for each ID in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with five columns, namely, ID, timestamp, value1, gender, and age columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create a sample DataFrame
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'timestamp': ['2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-01 12:30:00', '2022-01-01 13:00:00',
                      '2022-01-01 12:02:00', '2022-01-01 12:22:00', '2022-01-01 12:42:00'],
        'value1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M'],
        'age': [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# define a custom function to get the union of timestamp and other columns
def get_union(df):
    union_timestamp = df['timestamp'].unique()
    value1 = df['value1'].values[0]
    gender = df['gender'].values[0]
    age = df['age'].values[0]
    return pd.Series({'timestamp': union_timestamp, 'value1': value1, 'gender': gender, 'age': age})

# group the data by ID and apply the custom function to each group
result = df.groupby('ID').apply(get_union).reset_index()

# display the result
print(result)
```

For each ID, I would like to append union of timestamp on original timestamp. Besides, I will keep original timestamp and their respective values in value1, gender, and age columns. How can I achieve this?

So far, I tried creating a custom function. Then, I group my data by *ID* and applied my custom function. However, my custom function only works with different dates, and **not with different time values from same day**

What I have:

| ID | value1 | timestamp | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 80 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 65 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 2 | 65 | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 83 | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 63 | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | f | 8 |

What I expect:

| ID | value1 | timestamp | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | interpolated_value | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | interpolated_value | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 80 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | interpolated_value | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 65 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 2 | interpolated_value | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 65 | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 83 | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | interpolated_value | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 63 | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | interpolated_value | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | f | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe from your code doesn't match the table below it. So I'm not sure how you want to fill `gender` and `age`. Do you want to keep the first value for each `ID` as your code suggests? How shall `value1` be interpolated? The default is linear interpolation:

```py
union_timestamp = df['timestamp'].drop_duplicates()

df_out = pd.concat([
    pd.merge(df_g, union_timestamp, on='timestamp', how='outer').assign(ID=id_).sort_values('timestamp')
    for id_, df_g in df.groupby('ID')
])
df_out['value1'] = df_out['value1'].interpolate()
```

Output:

```
   ID            timestamp     value1 gender   age
0   1  2022-01-01 12:00:00  10.000000      M  20.0
3   1  2022-01-01 12:02:00  13.333333    NaN   NaN
4   1  2022-01-01 12:22:00  16.666667    NaN   NaN
1   1  2022-01-01 12:30:00  20.000000      M  25.0
5   1  2022-01-01 12:42:00  25.000000    NaN   NaN
2   1  2022-01-01 13:00:00  30.000000      F  30.0
3   2  2022-01-01 12:00:00  35.000000    NaN   NaN
0   2  2022-01-01 12:02:00  40.000000      F  35.0
1   2  2022-01-01 12:22:00  50.000000      F  40.0
4   2  2022-01-01 12:30:00  55.000000    NaN   NaN
2   2  2022-01-01 12:42:00  60.000000      M  45.0
5   2  2022-01-01 13:00:00  60.000000    NaN   NaN
```